# Terminal searching JDK in wrong PATH/Build failed, debugger for java

Tags: java, terminal

`` Error: could not open `D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\JDK\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg' ``

I get this error every time I try to run a java program. Before it was working fine when i had JDK 8 but i upgraded to 14. **I use VScode and I had deleted Intellij** but the file path hasn't gone and the terminal is trying to find the intelliJ JDK for some reason. I am a beginner to terminal too. I have tried setting up the environment variable for the correct path but that isn't working.The path variable doesn't have the intelliJ reference in it and i have even set up the JDK_HOME but even that isn't working.

Edit: I have downloaded a extension called **Terminal Manager** but don't know how to configure it.Will it work?(Edit: It doesn't, it's not what i thought it is used for)

Yet another edit: Is there a way to specify the path for JDK every time I use java commands in the terminal and does it have auto-completion(using tab). Should i just reset my machine because i can't seem to figure out this problem.

`Where java` in the command prompt gives `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`, not the path for the JDK 14. I updated the environment var path to point to the latest JDK but now i get `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` in the command prompt.

In **VScode**, on opening the **Configure JavaRuntime**,That is showing me 4 paths, 2 are the correct ones(one is labelled current), one empty and the invalid path. I can't seem to find any way to remove the incorrect one. Though it has the correct path, it still searches for the deleted file.

Update: The program now compiles but every time it shows:

```
 Build Failed
 Debugger for Java
 Proceed Fix Cancel
```

I click fix and clear the workspace cache but it doesn't work. It runs without the debugger but it would be better if it worked.

Comment: Look for PATH environment variable. Remove the IntelliJ reference from the path. The PATH variable should contain the JDK 14 path.

Comment: The path variable doesn't have the intelliJ reference, just VScode and python(i use that too) paths plus some other system paths.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _every time I try to run a java program_ How exactly do you try to run a java program? Do you open a command prompt window and enter `java ...` ?

Comment: Yes, i write java <class name> in the in-built terminal.

Comment: Open a _Command Prompt_ window and enter the command `where java`. What is the output of that command?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`

Comment: And thats the wrong path. It is an old installation of a Java JRE. Remove it from your PATH such that your new JDK path is first.

Comment: How do you remove that? In the JSON file of VScode? because that's already pointing to the correct one.

Comment: Join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219668/thelegend42-and-abra) ?

Comment: Don't have enough reputation for chat...new here

Comment: What does the command `java -version` display?

Comment: It shows the same error at the start of the question

Answer (score 0):

Install the "choose runtime" plugin this will allow you to select the runtime your self.
Start the IDE, use (Ctrl+Shift+A or Cmd+Shift+A on Mac), type "Choose Runtime", press Enter.
You will be able to download the latest version from here and it will be automatically configured to the config path

Comment: Isn't that a IntelliJ plugin, i am using VScode and have deleted intelliJ, thats why im getting that error.

Comment: ohh sorry for the confusionSettings for the JDK#
To access various settings for using the JDK, bring up the Command Palette (Shift +CMD + P) and use the command Java: Configure Java Runtime. You should be able to point to the correct path here

Comment: That is showing me 4 paths, 2 are the correct ones(one is labelled current), one empty and the invalid path. I can't seem to find any way to remove the incorrect one.