# Build failed, debugger for Java, cannot resolve

Tags: visual-studio-code, java-14

I get the the pop-up Build failed debugger for java.

I previously had [trouble running java after upgrading from JDK 8 to JDK 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362466/terminal-searching-jdk-in-wrong-path-build-failed-debugger-for-java) but now I can but I can't run the commands `javac` and `java` from the integrated terminal of **VScode**. I have tried [clearing the WorkspaceStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454523/how-can-i-fix-build-failed-do-you-want-to-continue-in-vscode)  but it isn't working.

I am not really familiar with all this; any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** The java commands are now working [by implementing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811332/cannot-run-java-from-the-windows-powershell-command-prompt). The debugger is not.

Comment: I know it's not an identical problem, but have you tried a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811332/cannot-run-java-from-the-windows-powershell-command-prompt

Comment: I followed this and the java commands starting working again. The problem was that the bin was not specified in the path. Thanks.